# Rust - How can I call functions from my src folder to code in my examples folder?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

If I have this function in `src/test.rs`

```
pub fn print_something(){
    println!("Something");
}
```

how can I call it in the `example/test.rs` ?

I've tried with `extern crate`, `mod`, `use` but none of these worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to declare the `test` module in src/lib.rs:

```rust
pub mod test;
```

Then, inside examples/test.rs, just use it as a library:

```rust
crate_name::test::print_something(); // Replace `crate_name` by the crate name
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using the actual crate name? I tried `crate::` and that didn't work.

Comment: @srgsanky No, you cannot, because it is a different crate? But why would you want that?